# How to make the textbox readonly on another textbox selection change using jquery in MVC4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

HI I want to make the Dropdown as readony on selection of another textbox.
I don't want to hide the Drop down

for ex
Centralized KOT,Order Ticket Entry and Direct Billing  is a dropdown with values Yes and No

if I select CentralizedKot as Yes then I want to make the Order Ticket Entry and Direct Billing  as readonly field but i don't wannt to hide the dropdown box

Comment: try using jquery. A good solution for you

Comment: Ys I Know but the problem is that it don't want to hide the textbox

Comment: So post your code what have you tried?

Comment: The textbox or dropdown will not be hidden unless you hide it explicitly. Post that you have tried, if you are yet to try something, search on net, there are lot of tutorials and help materials available on the net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the below JS for make textbox read only

```
  $('#TextBox_ID').attr('readonly', true);
```